# The use of the LIMIT clause in MySql doesn't work with subquery

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySql named `order_item` which contains the details of a particular order which has the following fields (and some other that I may find unnecessary to post here).

1. order_id
2. prod_id
3. qty_ordered
4. price

I need to calculate the best seller products. I'm using the following SQL statement.

```
SELECT o.prod_id, sum(o.qty_ordered) as qty_ordered, p.prod_img 
FROM order_item o, product_image p 
WHERE o.prod_id=p.prod_id AND 
p.prod_id IN(SELECT prod_id FROM product_image limit 1) AND
order_id IN(SELECT order_id FROM order_table WHERE od_status='Completed')
GROUP BY prod_id 
HAVING SUM(qty_ordered)>=5
ORDER BY prod_id DESC
```

The above query calculates the best selling products. The only question is that the subquery mentioned in the above statement

```
p.prod_id IN(SELECT prod_id FROM product_image limit 1)
```

doesn't work. MySQL complains

```
This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

This subquery retrieves the product image maintained in the `product_image` table where there are multiple product images for the same product and I need only one of them to display.

My server version is 5.1.48. Is there another way to get around this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your query is the line with the IN clause even needed?
You are already doing a join with:

```
WHERE o.prod_id=p.prod_id
```

It seems like the line you are talking about is redundant because the join has already happened? Also, there is no WHERE clause in the LIMIT query. Is there only 1 row in this table?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, MySQL doesn't support limit in IN subqueries.

However, what you can do is make a view, and select that view instead.

Make this into a view: SELECT prod_id FROM product_image limit 1

And then call it in your IN clause:

```
p.prod_id IN(SELECT prod_id FROM YOUR_VIEW_NAME_HERE)
```

I'm not sure if this is the best answer, but it works :)